# How pass Published var from one class (view model) as Published property in other class (view model) for binding to view of second view model

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm

I have FirstViewModel class with @Published property "myProperty".
In view FirstView I insert SecondView which has environmentObject SecondViewModel.
SecondViewModel also has own @Published var myProperty. myProperty in FirstViewModel and SecondViewModel must be the same (trigger each other).
How I can pass myProperty of FirstViewModel into SecondViewModel for bindint to SecondView.
SecondViewModel and SecondView must not know about FirstViewModel and FirstView.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class FirstViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var myProperty: String?
    // Some code and some methods
    // In this class I handle "myProperty"

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        self.myProperty = "Two"
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var vm: FirstViewModel

    var body: some View {

        SecondView()
           .environmentObject(SecondViewModel(myProperty: $vm.myProperty))
    }

}


class SecondViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var myProperty: String?
    // Some code
}

struct SecondView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var vm: SecondViewModel
    let items: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

    var body: some View {

        Picker(
            selection: $vm.myProperty,
            label: EmptyView()
        ) {
            ForEach(vm.items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item).tag(item)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Another words I need pass @Published var myProperty from FirstViewModel to SecondViewModel for binding to SecondView.

This code don't work, I got error "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'String?'"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `@Published` property in your second view model, you should use a `@Binding` so there's a single source of truth (the first view model):

```
class FirstViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var myProperty: String

    init() {
        self.myProperty = "Two"
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var vm: FirstViewModel

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $vm.myProperty)
        SecondView()
           .environmentObject(SecondViewModel(myProperty: $vm.myProperty))
    }

}


class SecondViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Binding var myProperty: String
    
    init(myProperty: Binding<String>) {
        _myProperty = myProperty
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: SecondViewModel

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: vm.$myProperty)
    }
}
```

I've simplified the example a little bit so that it compiles. You can easily change the types back from `String` to `String?` if you remove the `TextField`s that I just have to show the behavior.

Probably worth mentioning (since otherwise it will almost certainly appear in the comments) that there are some that will disagree with the architecture choice of using multiple view models like this, but I think that's outside of the scope of the question, which I took at face value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks what I need. But what if I need to have subscribers of myProperty in SecondViewModel?

Comment: You could use `onChange` in your `View` and then trigger something in your `ViewModel`. Or, pass a `Publisher` as well as the `Binding` to the view model.

Comment: Can you really use the @Binding property wrapper outside a view?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, you can. The only thing it doesn't do is provide an automatic update to a `View`, since it isn't in a view. But, you can still use the same semantics regarding the wrapped and projected value. However, this would work equally well changing from `@Binding` to `Binding<String>` as well

Comment: @jnpdx But what if I have in SecondViewModel subscribers which on sink change binding myProperty? In this case I receive alert "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior." and which showing it a loop.

Comment: `@Published var type: String = ""`

Comment: `$type.sink {receivedType in
            if receivedType == "someType" { self.myProperty = "three" }
 }`

Comment: This is a great example of what I mention in the last paragraph of my answer. This type of architecture is likely to lead to strange situations. I strongly suggest you adopt a more common pattern with a single source of truth and method of propagating changes. 

Also, if you have more followups, at this point, it’s probably good to start a new question where you can include all of the code/context. You have 3 answers here that address the original question as presented.

Answer (score 0):

In order for them to be in sync and be able to make changes to each other, I think they would have to know about each other somehow or at least one or the other has to know about the other.

The way I see it, `SecondView` only exists under `FirstView`, so `FirstView` will exist as long as `SecondView` exists. Therefore, it may be a good idea to use dependency injection to inject `FirstViewModel` (which also only exists as long as `FirstView` exists) as a dependency into `SecondView` like so:

```swift
struct FirstView: View {
    ...
    var body: some View {
         SecondView()
            .environmentObject(SecondViewModel())
            .environmentObject(FirstViewModel())
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var firstViewModel: FirstViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: SecondViewModel
    ...
}
```

One thing you might be able to do is create an extension to help sync to bindable properties, which just requires them both to conform to the `Equatable` protocol (and Strings do conform to this protocol) like so:

```swift
extension View {
    func sync<Bindable: Equatable>(_ published: Binding<Bindable>, with binding: Binding<Bindable>) -> some View {
        self
            .onChange(of: published.wrappedValue) { published in
                binding.wrappedValue = published
            }
            .onChange(of: binding.wrappedValue) { binding in
                published.wrappedValue = binding
            }
    }
}
```

You can then make use of this in your code like so:

```swift
struct SecondView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var firstViewModel: FirstViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: SecondViewModel
    ...
    var body: some View {
        Picker(
            ...
        ) {
            ...
        }
        .sync($firstViewModel.myProperty, with: $viewModel.myProperty) // Note the order in which u put the properties u wanna sync doesn't matter
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need any clarification or if this does not work. Happy to help!

Comment: Thanks for you answer. My case is very simple and this solution looks like a bit complex. Second view in my case contain few Pickers. Data in this pickers is filtering and depends on each other (which handling in SecondViewModel). And also "selection" of each picker (as a result) is handling in FirstViewModel). So second model should not know about first model. Also Second view can be embed in other views, not only first view.

Answer (score 0):

In views, you listen to published properties using @StateObject or @ObservedObject, for classes however you use combine to listen to a published property from another class.

In the first ViewModel:

- Create global shared instance of the class itself (singleton)

In the second ViewModel:

- Import Combine
- setup a cancelable variable
- reference the shared instance from first class
- Setup function to subscribe to a property in the first class
- Put the function in the initializer
  In essence:

```
class FirstViewModel
{
  @Published var firstProperty

  static let shared = FirstViewModel()
}

class SecondViewModel
{
  @Published secondProperty

  private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
  private let firstViewModel = FirstViewModel.shared

  init() {
    setupSubscribers()
  }

  func setupSubscribers() {
    firstViewModel.$firstProperty.sink { [weak self] firstProperty in
      self?.secondProperty = firstProperty
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I use in my project MVVM pattern and classes FirstViewModel and SecondViewModel are view models. And Singleton is not good idea in my case. These models should not know about each other.